# Is there a font that has the same horizontal width in every uppercased letter?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-size

im searching for a font that is looking like a normal typewriter font. Almost every monosized font has different sizes in their uppercased width. An "A" has a bigger width than a  "B". Is there a font wich has uppercased letters in the same width?

Comment: Every monospace font with uppercase letters is true for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110874

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font that doesn't move when text is edited](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/110874/font-that-doesnt-move-when-text-is-edited)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for, like Zach said, is a Monospaced font. A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width, or non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each occupy the same amount of horizontal space. [Read more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) This would also be true for uppercased letters.

[List of  a few popular Monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces)